# SAS: Change order of variable values in PROC TABULATE

Tags: sas, tabulate

I have the following sample data:

```
DATA offenders;
INPUT id :$12. age :3. sex :$1. residenceStatus :$1.;
INFORMAT id $12.;
INFILE DATALINES DSD;
DATALINES;
1,30,m,A
2,20,f,B
3,16,u,X
4,55,m,X
5,60,f,Y
6,20,f,A
7,34,m,B
8,63,m,X
9,23,m,X
10,19,f,A
11,56,f,A
12,25,u,X
13,31,u,A
14,24,f,B
15,27,m,A
16,20,m,B
17,21,u,A
18,43,f,A
19,44,u,A
20,41,m,B
;
RUN;

proc format;
 value agegrp 1-20 = '1-20'
              21-30 = '21-30'
              31-40 = '31-40'
              41-50 = '41-50'
              51-60 = '51-60'
              61-70 = '61-70';
 value $status 'A' = 'Status A'
                'B' = 'Status B'
                'X' = 'Status X'
                'Y' = 'Status Y';
run;
```

Now, I am creating a crosstable using PROC TABULATE:

```
proc tabulate;
class age sex residenceStatus;
table sex="", (ALL residenceStatus="") * age="" /misstext="0";
format age agegrp. residenceStatus $status.;
run;
```

But how can I change the order of a specific variable within the crosstable?

For example, in the example above the columns are:

```
   ALL            Status A       Status B       Status X       Status Y
   1-20 21-30 ... 1-20 21-30 ... 1-20 21-30 ... 1-20 21-30 ... 1-20 21-30 ...
f
m
u
```

What if I wanted `ALL  Status X  Status B   Status A   Status Y` instead? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `PRELOADFMT` is used to force a **specific** ordering of values of a `CLASS` variable.

Change the definition of the custom format `$status` to specify the `(NOTSORTED)` option and list the mappings in the desired output order.  NOTSORTED tells the procedure to NOT sort by the start values -- this affects the internals of the format and how it interacts with other procedures.

Then in the `TABULATE`, for the `CLASS` variable needing the specific order as defined, specify the options `ORDER=DATA PRELOADFMT`.  *NOTE: The default ordering is formatted value ascending.*

```
proc format;
 value $status (notsorted)
  'X' = 'Status X'
  'B' = 'Status B'
  'A' = 'Status A'
  'Y' = 'Status Y'
 ;
run;

proc tabulate;

  class age sex;                                 /* <---- default ordering */
  class residenceStatus / preloadfmt order=data; /* <---- custom ordering  */

  table sex="", (ALL residenceStatus="") * age="" /misstext="0";
  format 
    age agegrp. 
    residenceStatus $status.                     /* <---- defined with (NOTSORTED) */
  ;     
run;
```